# Split an NSString by character count?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

**What is the simplest way to split an NSString by the maximum number of characters?**

For example, if I have a string that is `204` characters long and I want to split it at `100` characters, it should yield an NSArray with three substrings (`100,100,4`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int len=0;

while( (len+100)<[string length]) {
    [array addObject:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(len,100)]];
    len+=100;
}

[array addObject:[string substringFromIndex:len]];
```

Don't forget to release the array when you have done.

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
- (NSArray *)chunksForString(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableArray *chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    double sizeChunk = 100.0; // or whatever you want
    int length = 0;
    int loopSize = ceil([str length]/sizeChunk);
    for (int index = 0; index < loopSize; index++) {
        NSInteger newRangeEndLimit = ([str length] - length) > sizeChunk ? sizeChunk : ([str length] - length);
        [chunks addObject:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(length, newRangeEndLimit)];
        length += 99; // Minus 1 from the sizeChunk
    }

    return chunks;
}
```